# ISO8601DateFormatter doesn't parse ISO date string

Tags: ios, swift, date, swift3, ios10

I'm trying to parse this

> 2017-01-23T10:12:31.484Z

using native `ISO8601DateFormatter` class provided by `iOS 10` but always fails.
If the string not contains milliseconds, the `Date` object is created without problems.

I'm tried this and many `options` combination but always fails...

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withDashSeparatorInDate, .withColonSeparatorInTime, .withColonSeparatorInTimeZone, .withFullTime]
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/swift-how-to-create-a-date-time-stamp-and-format-as-iso-8601-rfc-3339-utc-tim/28016619

Comment: Yes, I know that using `dateFormat` is the way, but I want to use native class of iOS 10... :(

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Prior to macOS 10.13 / iOS 11 `ISO8601DateFormatter` does not support date strings including milliseconds.

A workaround is to remove the millisecond part with regular expression.

```
let isoDateString = "2017-01-23T10:12:31.484Z"
let trimmedIsoString = isoDateString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\.\\d+", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let date = formatter.date(from: trimmedIsoString)
```

In macOS 10.13+ / iOS 11+ a new option is added to support fractional seconds:

> `static var withFractionalSeconds: ISO8601DateFormatter.Options { get }`

```
let isoDateString = "2017-01-23T10:12:31.484Z"
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.formatOptions =  [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
let date = formatter.date(from: isoDateString)
```

Comment: When was that added? I filed a radar about 3 weeks ago because it didn't have fractional seconds. It still doesn't seem to allow for selecting the number of decimal places though :( http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6095965782016000

Comment: It was added with the [macOS 10.13 / iOS 11 SDK](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter.options/2923300-withfractionalseconds)

Comment: No, it really wasn't. That wasn't there 3 weeks ago. Must have been added very recently. It may support back to 11.0 but it must only have been added in the past couple days. I even showed a colleague that it wasn't there just last week. :)

Comment: Could be. I read about it in the release notes / API changes when Xcode 9 was released but I didn't prove that the API was really available.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/swift-how-to-create-a-date-time-stamp-and-format-as-iso-8601-rfc-3339-utc-tim also provides some additional ideas and context re: pre 10.13 and post 10.13 approaches

Comment: Be careful withFractionalSeconds crashes up to 11.2. it is fixed in 11.2+

Comment: thx @hash3r i was wondering if I'm the only one that run into this problem

Comment: I was crashing for us also, documentation is misleading, thanks @hash3r

Answer (score 9):

For people that are not ready to go to iOS 11 yet, you can always create your own formatter to handle milliseconds, e.g.:

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static var iSO8601DateWithMillisec: DateFormatter {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        return dateFormatter
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let formater = DateFormatter.iSO8601DateWithMillisec
let date = formater.date(from: "2017-01-23T10:12:31.484Z")!
print(date) // output: 2017-01-23 10:12:31 +0000
```

It is slightly more elegant than writing a regex to strip out the milliseconds from the input string.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this will help to decode slightly different formats:

```
extension JSONDecoder {
    enum DateDecodeError: String, Error {
        case invalidDate
    }

    static var bestDateAttemptDecoder: JSONDecoder {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom({ (decoder) -> Date in
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            if let dateSecs = try? container.decode(Double.self) {
                return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: dateSecs)
            }

            if let dateSecs = try? container.decode(UInt.self) {
                return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(dateSecs))
            }

            let dateStr = try container.decode(String.self)
            let isoFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
            isoFormatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
            if let date = isoFormatter.date(from: dateStr) {
                return date
            }

            isoFormatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime ]
            if let date = isoFormatter.date(from: dateStr) {
                return date
            }

            log.warning("Cannot decode date");
            throw DateDecodeError.invalidDate
        })

        return decoder
    }
}
```

From: https://gist.github.com/th3m477/442a0d1da6354dd3b84e3b71df5dca6a

Comment: Mm282, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered same issue some months ago. And here's my solution for reference:

```
// *****************************************
// MARK: - Formatter extension
// *****************************************
extension Formatter {
    static let iso8601: ISO8601DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current 
        formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
        return formatter
    }()
    static let iso8601NoSecond: ISO8601DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current 
        formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime]
        return formatter
    }()
}

// *****************************************
// MARK: - ISO8601 helper
// *****************************************
    func getDateFrom(DateString8601 dateString:String) -> Date?
    {
        if let date = Formatter.iso8601.date(from: dateString)  {
            return date
        }
        if let date = Formatter.iso8601NoSecond.date(from: dateString)  {
            return date
        }
        return nil
    }

// *****************************************
// usage
// *****************************************
    let d = getDateFrom(DateString8601: "2017-01-23T10:12:31.484Z")
    print("2017-01-23T10:12:31.484Z millis= ", d?.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)

    let d2 = getDateFrom(DateString8601: "2017-01-23T10:12:31Z")
    print("2017-01-23T10:12:31Z millis= ", d2?.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)


// *****************************************
// result
// *****************************************
2017-01-23T10:12:31.484Z millis=  Optional(506859151.48399997)
2017-01-23T10:12:31Z millis=  Optional(506859151.0)
```

Comment: `formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current` is wrong. Why do you think Apple made ISO8601DateFormatter timezone defaults to zero seconds from GMT?