# Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException while using formatter to convert string to date

Tags: swift, exception, crash, ios11, dateformatter

I'm getting Crashlytics crash reports while using ISO8601DateFormatter with the formatOptions `.withFractionalSeconds` to parse strings like this

> 2017-01-23T10:12:31Z
>
> or
>
> 2017-01-23T10:12:31.484Z
>
> or
>
> 2017-01-23T10:12:31.484221Z

to date with this code:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
  let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
  formatter.formatOptions.insert(.withFractionalSeconds)
  result = formatter.date(from: string)
}
```

the crash message I'm getting is:

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
>
> Invalid parameter not satisfying: formatOptions == 0 || !(formatOptions & ~(NSISO8601DateFormatWithYear | NSISO8601DateFormatWithMonth | NSISO8601DateFormatWithWeekOfYear | NSISO8601DateFormatWithDay | NSISO8601DateFormatWithTime | NSISO8601DateFormatWithTimeZone | NSISO8601DateFormatWithSpaceBetweenDateAndTime | NSISO8601DateFormatWithDashSeparatorInDate | NSISO8601DateFormatWithColonSeparatorInTime | NSISO8601DateFormatWithColonSeparatorInTimeZone | NSISO8601DateFormatWithFullDate | NSISO8601DateFormatWithFullTime | NSISO8601DateFormatWithInternetDateTime))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that this crash caused by the option `.withFractionalSeconds` in iOS 11.0.* and 11.1.*.

To fix this you should change `#available(iOS 11.0, *)` to `#available(iOS 11.2, *)`

**More Details:**

Although the struct `ISO8601DateFormatter.Options` is available since iOS 10.0+, and the option itself `static var withFractionalSeconds: ISO8601DateFormatter.Options { get }` is available since iOS 11.0+. [Read Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter/options) and [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter/options/2923300-withfractionalseconds)

Using the option .withFractionalSeconds "crashes up to 11.2. it is fixed in 11.2+".
regarding this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847672/iso8601dateformatter-doesnt-parse-iso-date-string#comment97950217_41847949)

Answer (score 0):

To get the `Date` instance from `String`, try using `dateFormat` of `DateFormatter`, i.e.

```
let str = "2017-01-23T10:12:31.484Z"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str)
print(date)
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe the question is not complete
my goal is to format strings like "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" , or "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", so using ISO8601DateFormatter is cleaner than trying to parse with 2 if statements (although I'm using it as a fallback for older iOS versions)